# Woah, SF has top-banner ads?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

When I load SF question/answer view there's a banner ad that appears at the top and then quickly flashes away. Is this a bug?

I managed to get a pic :

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Top ads will show up on the site if you have less than 200 reputation.

As for it flashing away, do you have any ad-blocking software/plugins?

Comment: Ah. Yep that's it = )

Answer (score 3):

The ads are normal for users under 200 rep.

As for the flashing, are you running an AdBlock in Chrome?  I think this is due to an issue to the way the AdBlock works.  It doesn't have as deep of an integration with Chrome as it does with Firefox, so it actually hides the ads after they are loaded, hence the short flash and then disappearing.

The [Chrome Ad-block FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), has more info on how ads are blocked.

Answer (score 2):

No that's not a bug - those adverts appear until you clear 200 reputation - your screenshot shows you're currently at 133.

Comment: Wow, more incentive than ever before to get over that 200 mark!